# How to obtain a String between nested Tags

Tags: java, beanshell

Within a project we try to replace a Text within tags.
We try to get a string with beanshell out of an html file.

```
<code>
var testString = "<a href='test/keyword/common'>Here is our keyword which should be replaced</a><img src='test/keyword/again'/>
</code>
```

Now only the Keyword between the `<code>a</code>` Tags should be replaced.
Is this doable with regex or substring or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In *limited* cases you can do it with regexps. However I'd recommend an HTML parsing/manipulation library such as [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) or [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/). It'll give you a much more robust and (likely) a more readable/comprehensible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with JSoup. Is there a possibility to change only the document.body.text without loosing all html tags inside?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "<code>var testString = <a href='test/keyword/common'>Here is our keyword which should be replaced</a><img src='test/keyword/again'/></code>";
        string = string.replaceAll("(<code>.*?)Here is our keyword which should be replaced(.*?</code>)","$1Replaced with:$2");
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Try this : It is exactly what you wanted but I also recommend to use HTML parser to parse HTML tags.